# HTML color of navigation bar

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am designing a web page and I want the top navigation bar of my website to have a color like the image below.
This image is taken from the website of Virgin America airlines.
See how the color changes from left to right.
Any CSS/HTML tricks to accomplish this task.

[image]

PS:I did know how to frame this in words, so the poor title of the question.

Comment: And btw it will be done by linear gradient of css3 property.

Comment: Have you tried googling "css gradient"?

Comment: That's a bad question you have there.. Anyway, check this: [MDN - linear-gradient](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/linear-gradient)

Comment: @Bálint : No I was unaware of this function. I will try it. Thanks.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/api/mdn/ try this

Comment: Try this site. It generates the code for you: [Colorzilla](http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
div {
  background: linear-gradient(angle, start_color, end_color);
}
```

See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/linear-gradient